# Determining Logged in user email and ID in form Authentication using ASP.Net

Tags: forms, authentication

I have implemented the login and create user wizard in my application. However, when I log in the system, by default this is displaying the window identity, not the credentials with which I have logged in in the login form.

Any idea why this may be happening. Login and create user seems to be working fine.

Thanks for the help.
Yagya

Comment: Is this using the membership API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try looking at this article - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178344.aspx

or this should work...

```
 MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser();
 if (membershipUser != null)
 {
   string loggedinuser = Membership.GetUser().ToString();
   yourdiv.InnerHtml = loggedinuser;
 }
```

use the above with ***using System.Web.Security;*** this will enable membership

Also make sure your web.config is using forms, and not Windows auth.